# MS Access: Set focus on a Radio Button

Tags: ms-access

I have 6 radio buttons on a form. 
I want the form to open with the 3rd radio button selected.
Instead when I open the form it has the 4th radio button selected.

Thanks!

Comment: Are the radio buttons part of an option group?

Comment: Thank you! I set the default value in the Option Group properties.

Comment: Since you discovered your own answer (i.e., setting the default value), why don't you post it as an answer and accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting the default value in the option group of the radio buttons!